# How to get the schema validator from a mongodb collection using node.js driver?

Tags: mongodb-nodejs-driver

Is there a ways to get the current schema validator from an existing collection in mongodb 5? I want to write schema migration script for an existing schema by retrieving the current schema validator, adding the changes and updating it with

```
db.command({
  collMod: collectionName,
  validator: schema,
});
```

Mongo shell ([mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/)) provides `db.getCollectionInfos({name: "<collection_name>"})[0].options.validator` to get the schema validator. However, there seems to be nothing equivalent in [node.js driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/) to get the validator. Not sure why but it looks like this is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution. Are there any other solutions?

```
  const collection = await db.command({
    listCollections:1.0,
    filter: {name: '<collection_name>'}
  });

  let schema = collection.cursor.firstBatch[0].options.validator;
```